# upload image in form using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have contact form in my page and i collect users data, how can I add image attaching in this form, I want use multer  package  for it.

```
<form action="/profile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="avatar" />
</form>
```

Comment: You should refer any tutorials like https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_uploadfiles.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multer — A node package for handling multipart/form-data enctypes

video tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sMnqnvW81to&lc=z23htp54jwmhwni0nacdp43axbwhgu3y3fg0jwzwhatw03c010c

Comment: **thank you its work +1**

Comment: Mind if you mark my answer as resolved to help others.

Answer (score 1):

For uploading files in nodejs ,
You can use multer which allow us  to upload file in nodejs.

You can upload multiple files as well.(maybe require ajax for uploading)

For more reference
https://github.com/expressjs/multer